# How do you animate a background position with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, background

I have been trying to animate a background position move from a div. The div has a background and has something like this:

```
<div class="uppermenu" style="background-position: 0px -80px;"></div>
```

So, it works fine, and when I am making a mouseenter I want to change the background position animating it making it be like background-position:0px 0px, but it just doesn't work... I can change the colors and all, but I can't move the background. Is there a way to do it?

I've tried like this:

```
jQuery(this).children(".uppermenu").animate({"background-position": "0 85px"}, "slow");
```

And also like this:

```
jQuery(this).children(".uppermenu").animate({
    'background-position-y': '45px',
    'background-position-x': '0px'
}, 100, 'linear');
```

None of them changed my position. What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you attaching the animation to the child object of the dom instead of just using `$('.uppermenu').animate`?

Comment: because I am making into an mouseenter over the parent element... so, I need to make the animation on the children element....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for animating background position is:

```
.animate({backgroundPosition:"(-20px 94px)"});
```

You can also use a plugin for this at http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

Comment: Thanks, Ive tried that way too, still doesnt work, Im gonna check the plugin.

Comment: You have to use the plugin because jQuery cannot animate both x and y properties at once. Here's a [better explanation](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations).